# affect the result of sql query to textbox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

am using sqlserver 2008 and vb.net
i tried to affect the result of sql query to my textboxs.
here the code that i have tried

```
  Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Try
        Cn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT pk_veh, désignation, projet, version, [taille de lot] from [Cutting software].dbo.vehicule  WHERE désignation = '" & Form1.ComboBox3.SelectedValue & "'", Cn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rd.Read
            imp.TextBox1.Text = rd.GetInt32("pk_veh")
            imp.TextBox2.Text = rd.GetString("désignation")
            imp.TextBox3.Text = rd.GetString("projet")
            imp.TextBox4.Text = rd.GetString("version")
            imp.TextBox5.Text = rd.GetInt32("[taille de lot]")
            imp.Show()
        End While
        Cn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

while i checked the type of my columns i always have this error

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversion de la chaîne "pk_veh" en type 'Integer' n'est pas valide.'FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

here the type of my columns

pk_veh,[taille de lot] : int
désignation,projet,version : varchar[50]

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: hi @LarsTech, sorry i am newbie in vb.net i don't know how to use the parameters. have you any example to guide me

Comment: I gave you something to research.  Do the work.  Millions of posts on this.

Comment: ok thnx @LarsTech i'll search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the solution

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Try
        Cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT isnull(pk_veh,0)pk_veh, isnull(designation,'')designation, isnull(projet,'')projet, isnull(version,'')version, isnull(taille_de_lot,0)taille_de_lot from [Cutting software].dbo.vehicule  WHERE designation =  '" & Form1.ComboBox3.SelectedValue & "'", Cn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rd.Read
            imp.TextBox1.Text = rd.GetInt32(0)
            imp.TextBox2.Text = rd.GetString(1)
            imp.TextBox3.Text = rd.GetString(2)
            imp.TextBox4.Text = rd.GetString(3)
            imp.TextBox5.Text = rd.GetInt32(4)
        End While
        Cn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    imp.Show()
End Sub
```